# MS Access database opens in read-only mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-access, read-only

I have an Access database (format .accdb) in my Documents directory in my Sharepoint Online instance.

When I open the file, MS Access loads but it opens in read-only mode, showing the following:

[image]

If I click "Enable Content" the read-only does not change.

I have full access to the file and the directory it lives in; I can open .xlsx spreadsheets from the same directory and edit them in Excel. It seems specific to Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access is a strange one; you'd have to download it and open it from your local computer e.g. from desktop.  Then you can edit it, save it.  Then you'd have to reupload it to Sharepoint.  I don't fully understand why it behaves like this, but this is a way round it for you.

Indeed, for Excel it is not an issue.  I think it might be the nature of databases and how Access writes edits to the database... <- speculation...